# How to set a category in Sendgrid-Ruby v3?

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-ruby

Upgrading to SendGrid-Ruby V3 from V2.

In the past we set a category via

```
header = Smtpapi::Header.new
header.add_category("Congrats Credit")
```

I have searched the documentation for setting a category, but cannot find anything for V3. There is a reference where you can add 'categories' if you write your own JSON object, but want to use the API without writing my own JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's important to note that the Sendgrid-Ruby v3 is *not* using SMTP, it's using the HTTP API.

The answer to your question depends on if you're using the [helper class](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.rb#L86) [or not](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby/blob/master/examples/mail/mail.rb#L51). SendGrid has 'kitchen sink' examples for both.